# Is it safe to hot dock?

Tags: laptop, windows-10, docking-station

My technology administrator said to shut down my computer when I dock/undock my laptop from the docking station, because it will mess up Windows 10 if I don't. I have been hot docking (not shutting down), and not seen any negative side effects yet. There are 2 monitors, 1 keyboard, and 1 mouse attached to my docking station.

Should I take his warning? Is there something bad going on behind the scenes I don't know about? Or is there something bad that could potentially happen? If so, what?

Comment: I always hot dock. Is there anything important plugged into your dock? For me, I just have a monitor, USB mouse/keyboard, and Ethernet. Do you have any external drives or important devices on the dock?

Comment: Have you asked this Administrator for clarification?

Comment: @MC10 updated last sentence of first paragraph

Comment: @MC10 yes, but no straight answer

Comment: Sounds like a load of BS to me...

Answer (score 0):

Well, your administrator is right that it could cause some problems, but it won;t mess up your operating system. The problem with not shutting down is that your laptop could overheat, which is very bad for its hardware. Keeping your laptop plugged into the docking station when it is not needed is also a bad idea because a power surge or flickering could also damage the laptop hardware.

**To sum it up:** Turn off the laptop when its not in use for a while, and keep it off the docking station when you don't need to keep it on. Hope this helps!